# Why do hand held can openers stop working so quickly?

Tags: utensils

Is there any way to fix or adjust a hand held can opener?  I keep buying new ones because
within a month or so of buying them, they won't roll correctly on the can lip.

Comment: There are many different type of can openers. Please attach a picture of what you have

Comment: Cheap can openers tend to break quickly, good ones tend to last much longer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the proper way to maintain a can opener?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/10170/what-is-the-proper-way-to-maintain-a-can-opener)

Comment: Typically they either get dulled (can't cut through the metal as easily and therefore are more likely to pop off) or gradually get misaligned (and therefore are more likely to pop off).

Comment: I've been using the same one for 15 years.

Answer (score 5):

Can openers do break.

But if they're breaking quickly, then I'd suggest you're buying very cheap can openers.

One of these should cost $10-20 and should last at least a year.

[image]

Comment: at least ? I got one that is still going strong after at least 30 years.

Answer (score 3):

Truth of the matter is cheap ones don't last long, expensive ones also bought at certain stores may not last long just because they are expensive.  My advise, go to a restaurant supply store, see what they have and ask questions.  I bought one for $150 US and it's worth about someone paying me for the aggravation of the time spent to figure it out how to use it. It's one that the edges don't cut anyones fingers also don't open cans.  Go and get something priced about $20-25, good grips, easily washed, not to heavy and WITH a return policy.  I bought 6 now, and due to the earthquakes and loss of electricity I have in my area, it's been great for everyone I gave it to and I use it instead of  an electric can opener.  My Mom, who just left me to go to my Dad in the Heavens, bought the best electric can openers in the world 46 years ago, and although one is ugly green and the other ugly gold, popular 70's colors, those 2 can openers even have little things on the bottom to make them taller for bigger cans.  You can't find them now, they even have good knife sharpeners on the side.  Anyhow, restaurant supply, good handles, ask questions, good return policy. Good Luck!

Comment: $10 or so has always been enough for me. Get something with solid metal, not one of those punched out things held together by rivet. The rivet'll stretch and make it hard to get the cutter angle right and stable. Fit is *important*, and a cheap piece of trash won't hold a good fit for more than a few months use. It's possible to sharpen the cutter blade w a diamond file. Some types have replaceable cutting blades.

Answer (score 3):

It's really easy to cure generally. The main cause, be they cheap or otherwise, is the non forced roller cog (not the one attached to the twister, but the one that sits below the circular blade) siezes up with rust.  A vigorous blast with an old toothbrush, then undo the Phillips screw and remove. Carefully pull the blade and cog off - remember it's meant to rotate so if it's still stiff use a small pair of pliers and rotate it until it's lose and free. Pull the blade and cog off the spindle as mentioned and clean all parts quickly with the brush. If you have some WD 40 spray a bit onto a paper towel and then wipe the spindle with the towel. Reassemble. Should work a treat. I've literally just done this to a siezed can opener and it works like new. Took 3 minutes flat!

Comment: You might also want to post your answer on https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/10170/67 .  (at first I thought you hadn't answered the question, as the title is about why, but they did ask how to fix it in the body of the question ... but the other question is blatantly about maintaining can openers)

Comment: Thanks Joe, I think the answer covers all bases though. Why do they break? They seize up. How to fix them? As detailed above. How to maintain them? Make sure they don't seize up by keeping them rust free . Hope you agree! Kind regards from the UK

Comment: I added the parenthetical comments because I've seen answers get downvoted if someone thinks they didn't answer the question and some of the people are a bit ... overenthusiastic ... about it.  And so I said that more as an effort to warn away others who might not realize that any failings are in the question (by asking different things in the title & body) and not in your answer.

Comment: Is there any citable source on adequately removing WD-40? That is some dangerous stuff if ingested.

Answer (score 2):

The fact of the matter is they dont make them like they used to. I had one my grandma gave me in the early 80's.....and for some god awful reason i cant find it any more....it always worked ALWAYS! Never had an issue...They dont make them to last anymore...it just leads to more profits for the kitchen essentials market. hit yard sales...second hand stores or even online second hand places. You want one that wont stop working...buy one from the 60's-80's and you wont buy another one.